# Recursive function returns None in list

Tags: python, recursion, nonetype

```
flat_list=[]
        
def rec_flatten(alist):
    for i in alist:
        if i == None:
            return
        if type(i)==list:
            flat_list.append(rec_flatten(i))
        else:
            flat_list.append(i)
    return

rec_flatten(['a',['b','c'],'d',['e','f',['g','h']]])
print(flat_list)
```

Gives:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', None, 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', None, None]
```

How do I change this function so that the None returns aren't added to the list?

Comment: Because `rec_flatten` always returns `None`...

Comment: Your return statements are blank.  These will implicitly return `None`.

Comment: Just change this line `flat_list.append(rec_flatten(i))` to this `rec_flatten(i)`